# How to subscribe from iframe in reactjs to an event that is published in dojo

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dojo

I've the below code in dojo:

```
topic.publish("select",data);
```

I want to subscribe to this event and get the data in an iframe written in reactjs.

Here, the parent window i.e. the dojo code is loaded first and on a menu click the iframe in react code gets launched.

Can I have a global event listener that I can subscribe in my dojo code and use the same listener in iframe once it's launched?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try emit [CustomEvent](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/CustomEvent) instead, because I can't see how you can catch dojo/topic in react without importing it as dependency.

```js
function fireEvent(data) {
    let e = new CustomEvent('dojoevent', {detail: data});
    window.dispatchEvent(e);
}



window.addEventListener('dojoevent', function (e) {
    console.log('dojoevent', e.detail);
});

fireEvent(1000)
```

Comment: Yes thanks Kirill. I've tried this and this is working when iframe( in react) is being launched before the parent window ( in dojo) . But in my case, I'm launching the parent window first and then the iframe. So, the Event Listener is not available and we're not able to capture the dispatched event from parent. Can you please suggest any other solution? Thanks..

Comment: @Velurisaisruthi, then you'd better describe your problem clearly. How someone can know, that you have an iframe? :) So please, update your question, provide more details on problem you are trying to solve and it will increase chanses that you'll get the solution.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Kirill. I've edited my question accordingly.